# Do I have to add a ground wire that has been missing for 20 years?

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding, dishwasher

I am replacing a 20 yr old dishwasher in a 20 yr old house.  The wiring from breaker box connected to the old dishwasher had no ground wire.  Can I just attach the old white & black wires to the new dishwasher?  Will the independent connection to the breaker offer GFCI?  Or do I need to attach new ground wire?

Comment: Why is GFCI mentioned? Are you sure you know what GFCI means?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box for the dishwasher please?

Comment: I mentioned ground-fault circuit interrupter because I wondered if the circuit breaker might offer GFCI (thinking the original electrician might have a reason to not have a ground).  I also wondered if it was possible to create a plug to hook the dishwasher into a GFCI receptacle.  Thanks, good question.

Comment: Sorry, no pic, but here is link to lows manual, see page 3  http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/012505112577_install.pdf

Comment: Yeah, that’s not what we’re after.  ThreePhaseEel is fishing for the type of wire installation you are dealing with. Some of them don’t *need* ground wires because they provide ground an alternative way.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a ground? Are the old black and white wires in flexible metal conduit? Hard to believe a 20 year old house doesn't have a grounded dishwasher.

Comment: @Timbo -- we *need* a picture of the inside of the box you're trying to hook the dishwasher up to give any sort of definitive answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your setup is probably already grounded

You’re making a faulty assumption that there is no ground.

That is *highly unlikely*. You have a ~1999 house, and by then they’d been grounding houses for 35 years.  *It would be impossible for an electrician to find groundless wire* and it would never pass inspection.  And if it was done by a builder, that would never happen because they use high volumes of the correct stuff.

Far more likely, your house uses a wiring method that provides integral grounding and does not require any ground WIRES.

The #1 type most often seen is EMT metal conduit, This is the “gold standard” for industry. I maintain 4 buildings with not a single ground wire in any pipe.  It’s uncommon in residential homes but it’s certainly not rare; just two examples of towns that require it are NYC and Chicago.

Another type we see is the ground wire landed on a metal box (on the grounding screw which exists for that purpose) then grounding carried onward via direct contact with metal box.

We could confirm this positively if you could give us more details and/or a photo of the junction box in question.

### But yes, some type of grounding is required

If the electrician somehow found the motivation to sneak 60 year old Romex cable with no ground wire into a job, and dodged the inspector, then yes - that work would be illegal.  Further since it was not legal in 1999 at the time of installation, it doesn’t qualify for *grandfathering* (you aren’t required to update stuff that was legal when instaleld).  Therefore retrofitting ground is not an option available to you: **the entire cable must be ripped out and replaced whole**.   Further, you will need to inspect the entire house for other shortcuts.  Indeed, if the building inspector gets wind of that, you’ll get an order to do exactly that, *and* pull permits both for the demo and the rewire.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a ground wire. NEC 250.114(C) requires dishwashers to be grounded.

You cannot use a GFCI protected circuit as a replacement for a ground. When the GFCI method is used in place of a ground for a receptacle the NEC makes a very specific requirement to label the receptacle "No Equipment Ground", then follows with an informational note to refer to 250.114 that gives a list of equipment that requires an Equipment Ground, which includes dish-washing machines. Usually the installation instructions included with the dishwasher will also instruct to connect an Equipment Ground, the code requires following the installation instructions since they are part of the *Listing* (UL or other).

You can connect the Equipment Ground to another ground originating at the same panel, to the ground bar in the panel, or to the grounding electrode conductor.

Comment: Thanks to all, especially "NoSparks", for providing what I needed to know. Now I just need to find the ground bar in the panel, or the other two options - my responsibility.

Comment: @Timbo if you'll take a moment to take the [tour], then browse through the [help] you'll see that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to the answer, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the most (often, questions get more than one answer). That check mark also helps others to know that this issue has been resolved, so they don't spend time answering it, and for future seekers to know that this one has a workable answer that may also work for them.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a ground?  Are the old black and white wires in flexible metal conduit?  Hard to believe a 20 year old house doesn't have a grounded dishwasher.

Comment: @JACK  That's a great point, Jack. While most of the country uses cable,there are still some parts that run metal conduit, which of course serves as the ground connection.  I too was really surprised that a 20 year old house wouldn't have a ground.   I mean, that cable wouldn't even be available without a ground wire.

Comment: @Jack darn right!  I lay you dollars to donuts we’re dealing with EMT here.  This answer overlooked that, and OP seems to be thrilled with the answer, and from comments is not interested in investigating further. So another happy customer served, go us!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I'll settle for the donuts.... stay safe.

Comment: One more comment:  Assuming EMT, the OP need to be sure to properly connect the new DW using metal conduit to ensure a bonded ground connection. I say this because most DWs have electrical connections in different places.   Flexible metal conduit would suffice, but not plastic.

Comment: Yes, surprised/confused there is no grnd wth  b & w wires - only b&w coming out of the flex mtl cndt.  Mtl conduit ends at the wall, then the b&w wires go into a plastic tube tht goes into ktchn wll, down to the brkr bx.  Can I connect gw from the gw screw on the dw to the gw connection on the  grbg dspsl?  Easier than  running new ground wire to bsmnt circuit panel. Easier, but probably not code.

Comment: @Timbo Can you please post photos of this situation?